# Executing an R script from Perl

Tags: r, perl

I am trying to execute an R script from my perl script. I need to capture the output of the R script into a Perl variable. when I try to execute the R-script individually from the command line it works, meaning the R-script is working fine. The following is a small section of my Perl code.

```
#!/usr/local/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $base = `pwd`;
my $r_script= "Co-phen.R";
my $path='$base/$r_script';
      
save_R_env();

sub save_R_env {
    my $execute = `Rscript $path`;
    print $execute,"\n";
}
```

I get no results for `$execute`, and there are no errors printed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Single quotes prevent variable interpolation.  Use double quotes.

Change:

```
my $path='$base/$r_script';
```

to:

```
my $path="$base/$r_script";
```

See also:

```
perldoc perlop
```

This type of error is also detected by [perlcritic](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlcritic).

Also, you should [chomp](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html):

```
chomp $base;
```

Solution:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $base = `pwd`;
chomp $base;
my $r_script= "Co-phen.R";
my $path="$base/$r_script";

save_R_env();

sub save_R_env {
    my $execute = `Rscript $path`;
    print $? if $?;
    print $execute,"\n";
}
```